# Why would routes lose their aliases?

Tags: 8, routes, path-aliases

I have experienced this twice now on a Drupal 8 site.

Pathauto is at its current version and Drupal is 8.2.6.

What is happening is sometimes nodes 'lose' their aliases and revert back to being `node/1234` both on the front end, and the admin - even though they have alias records. The page cache maximum for the site is currently set to 1 hour.

Both times I was able to trigger this, these were the actions I was doing just before I noticed the aliases were now back to their paths:

- Implement a couple .htaccess rules to redirect an old non-Drupal URL to its new Drupal landing page
- Performed a database backup to a backup I had made 15 minutes prior

In *both* cases it happened. At first I thought maybe I messed up the .htaccess rule, and commented that out and pushed back live. That redirect is handled via event now. But then it happened again, with the database backup.

In *both* cases, only clearing the cache (either in the admin, or `drush cr`) fixed the problem. So what is causing it? How can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Anything in the error logs? Is it all nodes that lose the alias?

Comment: No logs, anything with an alias shows the system path. Cache clear, they come back.

Comment: How was the DB backup performed? Using [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) or PHPMyAdmin or some other tool/way?

Comment: Restored via Acquia Cloud panel. So I assume it executes a mysql import command.

Comment: `The page cache maximum for the site is currently set to 1 hour.` I wonder if this is causing the bug. Have you tried setting it back to the default and trying to reproduce the bug?

Comment: I didn't get a chance to yet because it happened on production.

Comment: I have a feeling that it's either that or something from Acquia is causing this.

Comment: I couldn't replicate it locally, that much I know.

Comment: If I were you, I would implement as well something like http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21pathauto%21pathauto.api.php/function/hook_pathauto_pattern_alter/8

In order to log this strange behaviour.

Comment: @Kevin Did you find out the cause and possibly a solution to your issue? We are currently experiencing the same issue on one of our sites.